# Missing artifact soapui:SoapUI:jar:5.2.1

Tags: maven, soap, soapui

I am trying to add soapui-5.2.1.jar dependency to pom.xml. Below is the dependency i added in POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>soapui</groupId>
        <artifactId>SoapUI</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But it is displayed the following error message:

```
 Missing artifact soapui:SoapUI:jar:5.2.1
```

I tried adding the parent & repositories as below:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>smartbear</id>
        <name>smartbear repository</name>
        <url>http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
    <artifactId>soapui-project</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1</version>
</parent>
```

Still same error message displayed.

Am i missing any thing here? like any repositories & parent tags?

**Note:** When i tried installing the jar file as local maven dependency, it was working fine. But i prefer not to use local dependency.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you navigate to the [repository](http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2), as you defined, you will see that SoapUI is here: http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2/com/smartbear/soapui/soapui/5.2.1/ So your pom needs to look like:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>smartbear</id>
        <name>smartbear repository</name>
        <url>http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
    <artifactId>soapui</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Note that capitalization does matter.

However, I am almost certain this is **not** what you want, unless you are building something that has SoapUI as a dependency! You are probably looking for the soapui-maven-plugin as described in the official documentation: https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html